# Cannot initialize Cluster Hadoop-2.7.1 and YARN

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

For simple program wordcount from examples submit job is failing even though all jobs are running.

```
 hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.1.jar wordcount hdfs://localhost:9000/input hdfs://localhost:9000/output
```

JPS

```
31265 SecondaryNameNode
31064 DataNode
30929 NameNode
31478 ResourceManager
32354 Jps
```

error

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.initialize(Cluster.java:120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$9.run(Job.java:1260)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$9.run(Job.java:1256)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.connect(Job.java:1255)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1284)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1308)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

**core-site.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/tmp</value>
  <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**yarn-site.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>
<property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
   <value>mapreduce.shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
   <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
 <property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>1</value>
  <description>Default block replication.
  The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created.
  The default is used if replication is not specified in create time.
  </description>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
   <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
   <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

**mapred-site.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name> mapreduce.framework.name </name>
    <value> yarn </value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

I tried many solutions from others SO post like changing **mapreduce.shuffle <-> mapreduce_shuffle** but none of them seems working. All directories exist and webpage is also available on localhost.

System configuration:

```
Ubunutu:15.10
Hadoop: 2.7.1
Java: open-jdk 7u95-2.6.4-0ubuntu0.15.10.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deleting all entries from **mapred-site.xml** it works don't know why?

In latest 2.7.2 release **mapred-site.xml.template** has been changed to

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
</configuration>
```

This gave me a clue and I tried and it works.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration of **mapred-site.xml** you mentioned:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name> mapreduce.framework.name </name>
    <value> yarn </value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

Here you have configured MR job execution framework to "yarn" which means using MRv2. If you want to run your job in traditional way,you can set framework to "classic" i.e. MRv1. Can you check with this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

delete spaces in : `<name> mapreduce.framework.name </name>`
 `<value> yarn </value>`

then try again

Answer (score -1):

Change your yarn-site.xml parameter

```
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
<value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19043970/cannot-initialize-cluster-please-check-your-configuration-for-mapreduce-framewo

Comment: I have seen that too there is no such configuration I have. It's fresh installation.